# Easy way to show a floating point integer without decimal positions in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, floating-point

Let's suppose we have 2 numbers, 2.0 and 2.1. There is an easy way to show or convert them respectively to "2" and "2.1"?

Sure I can do, for example, showFFloat (Just 0) 2 "", or showFFloat Nothing 2 "", but I use different arguments for each parameter, so the solution don't work for both numbers.

I can, for example, strip ".0", if present, from the end of the string after I showed 2.0 and 2.1, and that works, but it isn't exactly simple. And many other solutions solve the problem, but I can't think about a simple one.

Comment: well `show 2.1` should yield `"2.1"` - so I guess it's not exactly `2.1`?

Comment: Yes, but show 2.0 don't yield "2", but "2.0". And that's not the behavior I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing floating-point numbers is [surprisingly hard task](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=93559&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=610197641&CFTOKEN=10140114). The only implementation in `base` package I'm aware about is [floatToDigits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:floatToDigits), though it returns digits instead of strings:

```
Prelude Numeric> floatToDigits 10 2.0
([2],1)
Prelude Numeric> floatToDigits 10 2.1
([2,1],1)
```

(The second component of the result is exponent.)

Comment: This solves partially the problem, but is still too complex to obtain what I need. However thanks :)